# How to construct a histogram from a table?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
v <- c('a','a','h','b','h','a','j','h','a')
t <- table(v)
```

I wish to create a histogram in ggplot2 from this table. How can I do this without converting the table to a data frame or a vector?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this directly from table object but you can use vector `v` to make barplot with function `qplot()` and `geom="bar"` and number of observation will be calculated automatically.

```
qplot(v,geom="bar")
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a `dplyr` chain:

```
require(dplyr)

t %>% as.data.frame %>% ggplot(aes(x = v, y = Freq)) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity")
```

Inside the chain, `t` is converted to a data.frame object, but `t` will not be changed and there won't be a new data.frame object after the process. Perhaps that's also acceptable for your problem.

Comment: @user3749549 That is the chain operator in the latest version of `dplyr` which is versio 0.2. It lets you perform multiple operations after each other and chain them together with `%>%`. Just check to have the latest version of `dplyr` installed and loaded.